# What is the relationship between deployment and container level readiness probes?

Tags: kubernetes, healthcheck

I have a helm chart that defines my container's `readinessProbe` as:

```
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /health/readiness
      port: http
```

And when I deploy it I can browse to http://myservice.mydomain/istioBasePath/health/readiness and I get a response of `Healthy`.

But if I do a `kubectl describe pod` on one of the pods that comprise this service, I see this in the details for my container:

```
Readiness:  http-get http://:15020/app-health/my-servce-name-is-shown-here/readyz
```

Which is not at all what I setup in the deployment for my container. (If nothing else, it has a `z` in the name.)

Additionally, when I add the IP address of the container to that URL and run a `curl` from within the cluster, it does not respond with any text.  Running `curl` with the `-I` option shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 May 2023 23:26:11 GMT
```

(Again, no `Healthy` text is returned.)

Something is different here, but I am not quite sure what it is.  The URL for my "Deployment Defined" readiness probe works, but it returns the text `Healthy`.  The probe defined on the container (that I did not setup, and thought I was overriding with my deployment), just has a Http status result.

I thought I had only one probe going on, but clearly there is a difference.

Can someone explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using Istio which you did not mention in the question. By default (from version [1.5.2](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5.2/)) probe rewrites are enabled. This is required because of mTLS - for more details read the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/app-health-check/).

> The health check requests to the liveness-http service are sent by
> Kubelet. This becomes a problem when mutual TLS is enabled, because
> the Kubelet does not have an Istio issued certificate. Therefore the
> health check requests will fail.
>
> TCP probe checks need special handling, because Istio redirects all
> incoming traffic into the sidecar, and so all TCP ports appear open.
> The Kubelet simply checks if some process is listening on the
> specified port, and so the probe will always succeed as long as the
> sidecar is running.
>
> Istio solves both these problems by rewriting the application PodSpec
> readiness/liveness probe, so that the probe request is sent to the
> sidecar agent. For HTTP and gRPC requests, the sidecar agent redirects
> the request to the application and strips the response body, only
> returning the response code. For TCP probes, the sidecar agent will
> then do the port check while avoiding the traffic redirection.

Comment: Brilliant!  This is what I needed to know!!

Comment: Perfect. Good luck.